# Access to the file system for IIS application pool user, mutex problem

Tags: iis-7.5, log4net, mutex, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

My any applications run in pool with custom user account "IIS Universal".
I have 4 pools working under this account.
This account have full control access to the file and all parent folders:
[image]

But when applications try to write there are not access.
They write with log4net, whose log give me this:
[image]

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170116-00/?p=95186 Mutex has its own access control.

Comment: Thanks, but that write about case when 'two processes with different permissions' are.